# VS 2017 Fails to create Azure Mobile App scaffolding table controller

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-mobile-services

Trying to add a scaffolding table controller to a new project fails giving the error shown below. Seems like a bug in VS
[Error shown when try to a scaffolding table controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vopfo.png)

Installation Details
Windows 10.0.15063 Build 15063

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.2 (26430.13) Release
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.2.0+26430.13
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to following thread, mentioned by @Adrian Hall (MSFT).

[Cannot use Azure Mobile Apps Tables Controller Scaffold option in VS 2015 Azure SDK version 3.0](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de977545-ffc0-4c34-8d2d-9f046eae0155/cannot-use-azure-mobile-apps-tables-controller-scaffold-option-in-vs-2015-azure-sdk-version-30?forum=azuremobile)

*This is a known issue in VS 2017 (sorry!)
The fix is likely to be included in a future update to VS2017.  It is currently going through the validation process and is likely to be released in May.*

I just installed the latest updates of VS2017 and the issue still exist. Please create a normal controller and add features by yourself instead.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the reply